# Probabilistic classical algorithm on Deutsch-Jozsa problem

Tags: probability, algorithms, quantum-computation

Here is the description of Deutsch-Jozsa problem: Let $f: \{0,1\}^n \mapsto \{0,1\}$ be a function promised to be either constant or balanced ('balanced' means that $f$ outputs as many 0's as 1's).

**I need to show that a probabilistic classical algorithm making two evaluations of $f$ can with probability at least 2/3 correctly determine whether $f$ is constant or balanced.**

There is also a hint: *Your guess does not need to be a deterministic function of the results of the two queries. Your result should not assume any particular a priori probabilities of having a constant or balanced function.*

I'm a bit lost here.  My thinking is that if the two evaluations are the different, then $f$ is definitely balanced.  Otherwise, $f$ could be either constant or balanced.  But the chance of success would be depending on the probability of $f$ being constant, which is against the given hint.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Algorithm:**

> 1. Independently and uniformly sample two queries from $\{0, 1\}^n$, denoted as $q_1$ and $q_2$.
> 2. Evaluate $f(q_1)$ and $f(q_2)$. If $f(q_1) \neq f(q_2)$, output $\color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}$; otherwise, output $\color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}$ with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ and $\color{red}{\mathsf{constant}}$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$.

**Analysis:**

We have

\begin{align}
&P(\text{output }\color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}} \mid f \ \color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}) \\[5pt]
=\ &P(\text{output }\color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}, f(q_1) \neq f(q_2) \mid f \ \color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}) \\ &\quad + P(\text{output }\color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}, f(q_1) = f(q_2) \mid f \ \color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}) \\[5pt]
=\ &P(\text{output }\color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}\mid f(q_1) \neq f(q_2), f \ \color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}})\cdot P(f(q_1) \neq f(q_2) \mid f \ \color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}) \\
&\quad +P(\text{output }\color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}\mid f(q_1) = f(q_2), f \ \color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}})\cdot P(f(q_1) = f(q_2) \mid f \ \color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}) \\[5pt]
=\ &1\cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
P(\text{output }\color{red}{\mathsf{constant}} \mid f\ \color{red}{\mathsf{constant}}) = \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
&P(\text{output is correct}) = P(\text{output }\color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}, f \ \color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}) + P(\text{output }\color{red}{\mathsf{constant}}, f\ \color{red}{\mathsf{constant}}) \\
=\ &P(\text{output }\color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}} \mid f \ \color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}})\cdot P(f\ \color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}) \\
&\quad + P(\text{output }\color{red}{\mathsf{constant}}\mid f\ \color{red}{\mathsf{constant}})\cdot P(f\ \color{red}{\mathsf{constant}}) \\
=\ &\frac{2}{3}\cdot P(f\ \color{blue}{\mathsf{balanced}}) + \frac{2}{3} \cdot P(f\ \color{red}{\mathsf{constant}}) = \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}

Comment: @PSAPCEhard: Is this algorithm published anywhere?

Comment: @user1271772 I used $P(f\text{ balanced}) + P(f\text{ constant}) = 1$ in the last line.

Comment: @user1271772 I am not sure if the algorithm has been published. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question that you had, and @PSPACEhard's answer helped me a lot to understand the reasoning. So I'm going to provide another answer with a slightly different approach:

At first sight, you would think that with only two evaluations of $f$, your algorithm should always output "balanced", because there are many more balanced functions than there are constant. However, if you design your algorithm in a certain way, you can ignore the probabilities of the function being balanced vs. constant.So below, I will give the reasoning that would allow you to design the algorithm. Notation:
$$
f_b = \text{The event that the function is balanced}\\
f_c = \text{The event that the function is constant}\\
O_b = \text{The event that our algorithm outputs "balanced"}\\
O_c = \text{The event that our algorithm outputs "constant"}\\
Eq = \text{The event that }f(q_1)=f(q_2)\\
Diff = \text{The event that }f(q_1) \neq f(q_2)\\
$$

Now, given an algorithm that does two evaluations, and then output either `balanced` or `constant`:
$$
P(\text{answer is correct}) = P(O_b,f_b) + P(O_c,f_c)
$$
The term $P(O_b,f_b)$ can be written as:
$$
P(O_b,f_b) = \\
P(O_b|f_b) \cdot P(f_b) = \\
(P(O_b,Eq|f_b)+P(O_b,Diff|f_b)) \cdot P(f_b) = \\
(P(O_b|Eq,f_b) \cdot P(Eq|f_b) + P(O_b|Diff,f_b) \cdot P(Diff|f_b)) \cdot P(f_b)
$$

Now, since we want an algorithm that makes it's decisions *only based on what was observed*, we have:
$$P(O_b|Eq, f_b) = P(O_b|Eq)$$
and
$$P(O_b|Diff, f_b) = P(O_b|Diff)$$
Also, any non-stupid algorithm should output `balanced` with probability 1 in case of `Diff`, thus $P(O_b|Diff) = 1$. Taking the above observations into account, the expression becomes:
$$
P(O_b,f_b) = \\
(P(O_b|Eq) \cdot P(Eq|f_b) + 1 \cdot P(Diff|f_b)) \cdot P(f_b) = \\
(\frac{1}{2}P(O_b|Eq) + \frac{1}{2}) \cdot P(f_b)
$$
With a similar analysis we find:
$$
P(O_c, f_c) = \\
P(O_c|Eq) \cdot P(f_c)
$$
And so, going back to our original equation:
$$
P(\text{answer is correct}) = 
(\frac{1}{2}P(O_b|Eq) + \frac{1}{2}) \cdot P(f_b) + P(O_c|Eq) \cdot P(f_c)
$$
Now, we notice that if choose our values for $P(O_b|Eq)$ and $P(O_c|Eq)$ carefully (which we are free to do, because this is literally what defines our algorithm's behavior), we can make $(\frac{1}{2}P(O_b|Eq) + \frac{1}{2})=P(O_c|Eq)=\alpha$, and the equation above becomes:
$$
P(\text{answer is correct}) = \alpha \cdot (P(f_b) + P(f_c)) = \alpha
$$
which is not dependent any more on $f_b$ or $f_c$!

So let's see what values achieve this design:
$$
\frac{1}{2}P(O_b|Eq) + \frac{1}{2} = P(O_c|Eq)\\
\text{but } P(O_c|Eq) = 1 - P(O_b|Eq)\\
=> P(O_b|Eq) = \frac{1}{3} \text{ and } P(O_c|Eq) = \frac{2}{3}
$$
And $P(\text{answer is correct}) = \alpha = \frac{2}{3}$

And so you get the algorithm described in @PSPACEhard's answer.

Of course, you can reach this conclusion in shorter ways, but that was the pathway that worked for me.